# spawned process in node.js exiting immediately

Tags: node.js, spawn, avconv

I'm trying to spawn an avconv process inside node.js.
It should receive data on `stdin` and output converted data to `stdout`

While the command works in the shell, it immediately closes in node.js and I don't know why:

```
avconv -v quiet -i pipe:0 -vn -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le pipe:1
```

That just works, and in node:

```
var a = spawn('avconv', ['-v quiet -i pipe:0 -vn -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le pipe:1']);

a.on('exit', function(code) {
    pr(code, true);
})
```

I immediately get a '1' exit code.
Can anyone tell my what's going wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't your command arguments be separate strings?

Comment: Don't worry, that gets the same result

Comment: Have you tried to pipe stderr to see the error description?

Comment: Oh no, you're right. They WERE separate strings first, but in the order of `['-v quiet', '-i pipe:0']`, I did not know it automatically quoted them then...

Comment: The quoting is actually shell-specific. I'm adding an answer detailing this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to separate the argument array yourself:

```
var a = spawn('avconv', ['-v', 'quiet', '-i', 'pipe:0', '-vn', '-f', 's16le', '-acodec', 'pcm_s16le', 'pipe:1']);
```

The space delimitation you are used to from command line work is provided by your shell (bash, zsh...). The shell breaks up your command into argument using spaces and lets you say "I want this as a single argument" by adding quotes.

Comment: There is any way to get & print this kind of error with spawned processes? any event that I can listen to etc.? thanks

Comment: specifically, when a root permission is required in order to execute some bash script as a child process (using spawn). Which event should I listen to in this kind of case?

Comment: @YairNevet You're better off asking a new question, this one has absolutely nothing to do with that...

Comment: In my case I was not listening for stderr which was being thrown.